# What do I do if I don't have anyone to write my letters of recommendation for undergraduate research programs?

Tags: mathematics, recommendation-letter, research-undergraduate

I'm currently a second year student in maths and I want to apply to some REUs but I haven't made any remarkable relationships with my profs or anyone in the department. As well, I've just been an average student, just As and Bs, so I don't have anything exceptional to show for my attendance in my profs' classes. Thus, if anyone has any advice on what I can do for LORs, I'd appreciate it.

**Additional info:** I am doing research in my university, just not in maths, it's in pedagogy, but my supervisors don't know what's going on in my classes. I also have emailed this great prof I had last year once this year and have asked her for an LOR already, but I don't know how wiling she will be to give me another one since it's been a couple of months since we've last talked.

Comment: Instead of suggesting an edit to [this post](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/60640/) to add a "Thanks" paragraph in the body of the question, please [merge your accounts](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you'll take ownership of that post. Then you should "thank" those who answered by [voting up those you found useful](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and potentially accepting one. You will also be able to leave a *comment* on the question and/or answers letting others know how it turned out.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by _she will be to give me **another** one_. Did she write an LoR for you for something else already?

Answer (score 1):

Just go talk directly to people who might be interested in working with you. They won't be far away, anyway. You have to build up a reputation to get LoRs, and given your current status you just won't have it.